# How to compute probability of false rejection for a variance test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, variance

Suppose I'm testing a product by taking a sample of size $N$: if the (population) variance $\sigma^2$ is higher than $\sigma^2_\text{max}$, the product should be rejected. Then I can determine the sample variance $s^2$, and use
\begin{equation}
\frac{(N-1)s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{N-1}
\end{equation}
to compute a $(1 - \alpha)$ confidence interval for the population variance $\sigma^2$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{(N-1)s^2}{b} \leq \sigma^2 \leq \frac{(N-1)s^2}{a},
\end{equation}
with $a = \chi^2_{1-\alpha/2, N-1}$, $b = \chi^2_{\alpha/2, N-1}$. If $(N-1)s^2/a > \sigma^2_\text{max}$, I reject my product.

Based on this, how can I compute the probability of false rejection?

And what would be the probability of false rejection if I'd use $s^2$ directly, that is, reject if $s^2 > \sigma^2_\text{max}$?